# Laravel 5.2 form model binding - displaying model with() empty relationship

Tags: laravel

SOLVED, something else was causing the error, not an empty relationship.

I am having some trouble making this work. I have a large form that is combining 4 tables. For my example I will just use 3. Here is what I send to the view:

```
$student = Student::with('primaryInsurance')->with('secondaryInsurance')->findOrFail($student_id);
```

The form works fine if the student has both primaryInsurance and secondaryInsurance but I get a "Trying to get property of non-object" if one or both are not in the table. How can I avoid this?

Here are a couple fields from my form:

```
{{ Form::text('last_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control required']) }}
{{ Form::text('primaryInsurance[insured_name]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
{{ Form::text('secondaryInsurance[insured_name]', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

From the student model:

```
public function primaryInsurance() {
return $this->hasOne(StudentInsurance::class, 'student_id', 'student_id')->where('is_primary', '=', 1);
        }
public function SecondaryInsurance() {
return $this->hasOne(StudentInsurance::class, 'student_id', 'student_id')->where('is_primary', '=', 1);
        }
```

Comment: do you think you could share what your `scopeWith()` function looks like? Unless that is a function that ships with Laravel that I am unfamiliar with

Comment: @dargue3 https://laravel.com/api/5.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_with

Comment: ugh something else was causing the error... I thought it was because of empty relationship.

Answer (score 1):

First, combine your `with` query to make your code cleaner. Like so:

```
$student = Student::with('primaryInsurance', 'secondaryInsurance')->findOrFail($student_id);
```

Next, in your view check that the object is set (I think you should be using an object here versus array - that's what's causing the error I believe). You'll have to test. Your issue can also be that you're wrapping the object in ' '. Don't. I'd need to see your controller logic to get a better sense if this doesn't work.

```
{{ Form::text($primaryInsurance->insured_name, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

You can also do a ternary on this as well to default to `null` if doesn't exist:

```
{{ Form::text((($primaryInsurance->insured_name) ?: null), null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Comment: according to [the laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) it seems like the `with` query just accepts them as arguments and not an array... are you sure of your answer?

Comment: Yes, definitely. In the link you shared. Go to **Eager Loading Multiple Relationships**

Comment: Yeah that was what raised my initial question, it has them as multiple arguments in that example.

Comment: He wants to include both primary and secondary insurances. This does that. It's the exact same thing as including the `with` query twice like he originally had it.

Comment: I just meant that you had the relationships being passed as an array a few minutes ago, you've fixed it now.

Comment: Yeah, it was my bad. Writing off memory here. ;)

Comment: and doesn't matter anyways. Just tested. Can be an array - it's converted/treated as such anyways. https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php#L1021